# Query Formatting on Access

Tags: ms-access

I am stuck on one query and been pulling my hair on how I can do it without having to ask experts.

I have 2 tables:

Table1, Table2 - All tables have username as primary.

Each username have multiple entries with different shipping_address.

I simply want to display a query that is grouped by the username, displaying just one username per group of shipping_address.

I hope I make sense.

I just want to get rid of the repeating names...  Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Could be:

```
Select
    username,
    shipping_address
From
    Table1
Union
Select
    username,
    shipping_address
From
    Table2
```

**Union** will force Distinct on the result set.